# List cookbook dynamically without sub-shell

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I can retrieve the cookbook list by invoking `knife` in a sub-shell (and then parse the output) such as:

```
cb = `knife cookbook list`
```

another approach is to invoking the ruby classes/modules directly such as:

```
require("chef")
require("chef/knife")
Chef::Config.from_file(knifePath) #knifePath is declared a priori
cookbooks = Chef::Knife.run(["cookbook", "list"])
puts(cookbooks) # => nil
```

How can I store the data printed on screen by calling `Chef::Knife.run()` into a variable?

Comment: @Holger Just, you have renamed the title of my question. i thought the keyword should be placed there for a better search. but i am cool with whatever you decide...

Comment: Putting tags into the title is frowned upon on all StackExchange sites. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/217589.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look outside of `knife` for this one. Knife delegates to `Chef::CookbookLoader` (lower down the stack) and therefore you can just use the cookbook loader directly:

```
require 'chef/config'
require 'chef/cookbook_loader'

Chef::Config.from_file(path)
cookbooks = Chef::CookbookLoader.new(Chef::Config.cookbook_path).map(&:cookbook_name)
```

For example, [`knife-spork`](https://github.com/jonlives/knife-spork/blob/master/lib/knife-spork/runner.rb#L106-L108) uses this pattern to load the cookbooks.

Note that you will get the actual cookbook objects, not just their names. If you want something a little more lightweight, you could just iterate over each `cookbook_path` and look for a `metadata.rb`:

```
# https://gist.github.com/fnichol/4343327
class MetadataChopper < Hash 
  def self.extract(metadata_file)
    mc = new(File.expand_path(metadata_file))
    [mc[:name], mc[:version]]
  end

  def initialize(metadata_file)
    eval(IO.read(metadata_file), nil, metadata_file)
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    self[meth] = args.first
  end
end

require 'chef/config'
cookbook_paths = Chef::Config.from_file(path).cookbook_path

cookbooks = Dir[*cookbook_paths.map { |p| "#{p}/**/metadata.rb" }].collect do |metadata|
  MetadataChopper.new(metadata)[:name] || File.basename(File.dirname(cookbook))
end
```

Comment: firstly, thank you for your reply and for all the amazing job you do around the chef community. secondly, i am trying to interact directly with the chef server rather then local cookbook directory. is there any resolution for such use case?

Comment: i followed the link. the cookbook section on the readme is empty. although ridley is great, do you have any other lead?

Comment: and it is kinda strange that i cannot use one of the `Chef::Knife` modules to achieve it, since it is a feature which `knife` has.

Comment: You mean like this? https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-connectivity-test/blob/master/bin/check#L309-L312